# How to stop setInvterval based on a value change?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Would someone please explain to me why this loop never stops?

```
const interval2 = setInterval(() => {
    const a = "false"
    if (a == "true"){
        clearInterval(interval2)
    }
    console.log("Hello");
    a == "true"
  }, 1000);
```

Output:

> Hello
>
> Hello
>
> Hello
>
> Hello
>
> ..

As I understood clearInterval should terminate the interval. but it just keeps on going.

Comment: Because `const a` is being declared `false` again on each interval.

Answer (score 2):

In second line you assing "false" to a constant, and then you check if it is equal to "true". You need to declare **a** as variable in another scope, outside interval's callback.

```js
let a = "false"
const interval2 = setInterval(() => {
    if (a == "true"){
        clearInterval(interval2)
    }
    console.log("Hello");
    a = "true"
  }, 1000);
```

Also in last line of callback you have weird statement: **a == "true"**. It's probably should be **a = "true"**

Answer (score 0):

This happens since every time `setInterval` repeats a is set to "false" and thus `a == "true"` is never satisfied and this loop never stops. You can fix this by declaring the variable outside.

Also, we can not reassign a value to `const` variable, so we need to use `let` instead.

Also, to reset the value of `a` to `"true"` use `a = "true"` instead of `a == "true"`

```js
let a = "false"
const interval2 = setInterval(() => {
  if (a === "true") {
    clearInterval(interval2)
  }
  console.log("Hello");
  a = "true"
}, 2000);
```